# Are nested Templated Controls permitted

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a Templated Control that works correctly in XAML documents. However, when I include it in the XAML body of another Template, it doesn't work correctly. It displays, but its `OnApplyTemplate()` method is never called.

Can I use "nested" Templated Controls?

Comment: So it displays the original template?

Comment: The nested templated control displays without the values of the Dependency Properties that have been set in the XAML. At the Page level, it reflects the settings. When it's nested in another control, they are ignored. Further, the `OnApplyTemplate()` method is called in the first case, but not the second.

Comment: Have you defined a style for your custom control?

Comment: This might just be a workround and not a solution, but why not just use `UserControls` instead of a `CustomControl` with a custom `Template`?

Comment: TomerAgmon-that's exactly what I did to get around the problem, but I have the feeling that I should have been able to make it work the "right" way. My actual code is too large to include, but I'm going to do a "minimum" case to see if I can reproduce the problem, then post that.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple example of nested Templated Controls which worked without problem. So the simple answer is yes, nested Templated Controls work correctly. I still haven't determined why my real code isn't working, but I'm sure it's user error. While UserControl's are easier, at least for me, both these Templated Controls included`<ContentPresenter>` markup, and I don't know how to do that in a UserControl.

But that's another question.